# Calculate $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\left(\int_0^1 k(x-1)x^k (\log x)^{-1} \, dx\right)$

Tags: limits

How to find the following limit without evaluating the integral? 
$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\left(k\int_0^1 (x-1) x^k (\log x)^{-1} \, dx\right)$ , $k>-1$

Comment: What does $\log^{-1}$ mean?

Comment: Might it be that $\left(\log x\right)^{-1}$ was intended?

Comment: it means $1/log(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_k(x)=(x-1)x^k(\log(x))^{-1}$. Note then that $f_1\in L^1[0,1]$, $f_k$ is a positive sequence, and $f_{k+1}(x)\leqslant f_k(x)$. So, you can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem to get that the limit is zero.

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to include a factor of $k$ inside the integral .I fixed it .The limit should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that 
$$x < \frac{x-1}{\log x} < 1 
    \qquad \textrm{for} 
    \qquad 0 < x < 1.$$
(This is related to the first inequality [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/29/).)
In addition 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} (x-1)/\log x = 0 
    \qquad \textrm{and}
    \qquad \lim_{x\to 1} (x-1)/\log x = 1.$$
Therefore, for $k > 0$ 
$$\int_0^1 dx\,  k x^{k+1}  
    < \int_0^1 dx\, k\frac{(x-1)x^k}{\log x}  
    < \int_0^1 dx\,  k x^{k}$$
and so 
$$\frac{k}{k+2} < \int_0^1 k\frac{(x-1)x^k}{\log x} \, dx < \frac{k}{k+1}.$$
By the [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) we have 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^1 k\frac{(x-1)x^k}{\log x} = 1.$$